# How do I show that these sets are the basis for weak topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a polish space and $Prob(X)$ be the set of Borel probability measures on $X$.

Assume that "for any sequence $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ in $Prob(X)$, $\lim_n\mu_n =\mu$ iff $\lim_n\int_X fd\mu_n =\int_X f d\mu$ for every $f\in C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$."

Then, how do I show that finite intersections of sets of the form $\{\mu: a<\int_X fd\mu <b\}$ are a basis for the topology on $Prob(X)$?

Comment: In my copy of Billigsley's book on p. 239 it is stated that under continuum hypothesis (which implies that each  subset of the space has a non-mesurable cardinal) the topology genertated by your family is metrizable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In p.238, assuming $X$ is separable, Billingsley proves this without assuming continuum hypothesis. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ consist of all unions of finite intersections of sets of the form $\{\mu: a<\int f d\mu <b\}$. This gives a topology on your space. What you have to show is that $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for every bounded continuous function $f$ iff $\mu_n \to \mu$ in the topology $\tau$. Suppose $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\tau$. Fix any bounded continuous function $f$. Consider $\{\nu: \int f d \nu -\epsilon <\int f d\mu <\int fd \nu +\epsilon\}$. This is a neighborhood of $\mu$, so $\mu_n$ lies in this set for  $n$ sufficiently large. This gives $|\int fd \mu_n -\int fd \mu | <\epsilon$ for  $n$ sufficiently large. We have proved that $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$.

Conversely, suppose $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$ for every bounded continuous function $f$.  Consider any basic neighborhood $v$ of $\mu$, say $\{\nu: a_i <\int f_i d\mu <b_i, 1\leq i \leq n\}$. The fact that $\int f_id\mu_n \to \int f_i d\mu$ for each $i$ shows that $\mu_n$ lies in this neighborhood for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you! So now, we have $"\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\tau$ iff $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $T$". ($T$ denotes the topology originally given on $Prob(X)$. Why does this imply that $T\subset \tau$? To show this, when we pick an element $\mu \in cl_\tau(S)$ (closure of $S$ with respect to $\tau$), there **must** exists a sequence $\mu_n$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\tau$. Why does this sequences exist?

Comment: Would you please check this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3487790/44669

Comment: @Rubertos p. 239 (end of third para) in Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures says that the topology with the specified basic open sets is metrizable. So my answer shows that there is metrizable topology $\tau$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$  in $\tau$ iff $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$ for all bounded continuous $f$. In your question you hav enot completely defined $\tau$. If you choose the metrizable one in which conergence of sequences is as specified then everything is fine.

Comment: May I ask you which edition it is? I have Billingsley's book of second edition wiley series, but p.239 is an appendix M.5 which is about compactness, nothing says about metrizability.

Comment: Let me be clear at this moment. The given topology in my post is metrizable by so called "the Prokhorov metric". I know this fact. However, to show that the given topology and $\tau$ coincide, we need to know that $\tau$ is **also** metrizable, right? Do you mean that Billingsley's book has this proof?

Comment: @Rubertos Billinglsey shows metrizable whenever the metric  space is separable. His arguments are lengthy so I will request you to go through the book.

Comment: Well, I studied that book, so I know that fact. I think there is a misunderstanding here. Let $T$ be the topology described in the post and $\tau$ be the topology generated by sets of the form $\{mu:a<\int fd\mu <b\}$. I **know** that (i) $T$ is metrizable when $X$ is separable, and you showed that (ii) "$\mu_n\to \mu$ in $T$ iff $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\tau$". So we know that $\tau \subset T$. However, to show that $T\subset \tau$, I think we need to further show that $\tau$ is metrizable! But Billingsley only shows that $T$ is metrizable,not $\tau$.

Comment: Only assuming $T$ is metrizable, how can we show that $T=\tau$..? And thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: @Rubertos I am unable to understand your definition of $\tau$. Please tell me what exactly your $\tau $ is. You did not define it in your question since specifying convergent sequences and their limits does not specify a topology.

Comment: $\tau$ is the topology generated by the sets $\{\mu:a<\int_X fd\mu <b\}$. I am following your notation.

Comment: I clearly described the situation on the post in the link in the comment above.

Comment: @Rubertos Billingsley shows that topology generated by these sets is metrizable under continuum hypothesis. Are you willing to assume continuum hypothesis?

Comment: Well, I want to avoid it if it is possible.. but on which page is the proof??

Comment: Since the point here is to show that $\tau=T$, not that $\tau$ is metrizable, maybe one can avoid continuum hypothesis I guess..

Answer (score 0):

For each $f\in C_{b}(X,\mathbb{R})$, define the semi-norm $p_{f}(\mu)=\left|\left<f,\mu\right>\right|$. The space is generated by the finite intersection of balls $B_{f_{1}}(r_{1}),...,B_{f_{n}}(r_{n})$.

Comment: My question is why is that so..? How does finite points $f_1,...,f_n$ can generate all $f$'s?

Comment: That is the weak-star topology generated by those semi-norms, that is pure by definition.